# How to search from root of project using silver searcher in vim?

Tags: vim, ag

I have silver searcher set up in vim and would like to search from the root of a project directory without having to explicitly passing in the file path.

For example, let's say I'm at `/project_root/lvl1/lvl2`.

I want to search for a word starting from `/project` without having to type `:Ag word ../..`.

Is there a way to do so?

Comment: How do you know you've reached the root of a project directory?

Comment: Well CtrlP defines root of a project directory as a directory that contains `.git` folder.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the original Ag ([`rking/ag.vim`](https://github.com/rking/ag.vim)) is deprecated. The owner recommended moving back to Ack, but there is an active development in an Ag fork at [`albfan/ag.vim`](https://github.com/albfan/ag.vim). Using this version of Ag, you can enable project discovery by the following setting (`:help g:ag.working_path_mode`):

```
let g:ag.working_path_mode='r'
```

You may need to prepend `let g:ag={}`. Also, note that running `:Ag` with this option will silently `:cd` you to the project directory.